# I am trying to populate database with the image, image-name, image-number and image-price but only image column is filled

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2012

I am using angular as front-end and .NET Web API as backend and SQL Server 2012. I am trying to populate my database with image, image-name, number, and price but only the image is being populated.

Angular

**image.component.ts**

```
imageUrl:String="";
 fileToUpload:File=null;

 handleImageChange(file: FileList){
   this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload=(event:any)=>{
     this.imageUrl=event.target.result;
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
 }
uploadImage(imageData){
    console.log(0)
    let name=imageData.name;
    let number=imageData.number;
    let price=imageData.price;
    this.service.uploadImage(this.fileToUpload, name, number, price).subscribe(
      data=>{
        alert("successfully uploaded");
        this.productForm.reset();
        this.imageUrl="";
      }
    );
  }
```

**image.service.ts**

```
 baseUrl:string="http://localhost:62215/api/product/";

  uploadImage(fileToUpload:File, imagename:string, num:string, price:string){


    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file",fileToUpload,fileToUpload.name);
    formData.append("Imagename",name);
    formData.append("Number",num);
    formData.append("Price",price);

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+"UploadImage",formData,this.httpOptions);  
  }
```

.NET Web API

**ProductController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadImage")]
public IHttpActionResult UploadImage()
{
    HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            using (FreeShareEntities obj = new FreeShareEntities())
            {
                foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = Request.Files[file];
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + postedFile.FileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    ImageDemo image = new ImageDemo();
                    image.Name = Request["name"];
                    image.Image = postedFile.FileName;
                    image.Number = Request["num"];
                    image.Price = Request["price"];

                    obj.ImageDemoes.Add(image);
                    obj.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

What I am expecting is to populate all fields of my database table but not only one field.

Comment: You have to check the request containing the data using break point

Answer (score 0):

The key that you are getting from the Request is different from the Form Data key that you are sending.

```
formData.append("Imagename",name)
image.Name = Request["name"];
```

It should be

```
image.Name = Request["Imagename"];
```

Same with other mismatches.

If it still doesn't work, I would suggest an alternative. You're sending your data using form data might as well utilize the FromForm attribute.

Ex.

```
public IHttpActionResult UploadImage([FromForm]UploadDto dto)
{
    var postedFile = dto.File;
    var filePath = 
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + postedFile.FileName);
    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

    ImageDemo image = new ImageDemo();
    image.Name = dto.Name;
    image.Image = postedFile.FileName;
    image.Number = dto.Number;
    image.Price = dto.Price;

    obj.ImageDemoes.Add(image);
    obj.SaveChanges();
}

public class UploadDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number{ get; set; }
    public int Price{ get; set; }
    public IFormFile File{ get; set; }
}
```

I've been using this approach for a while now and it works great. Remember that the key you are appending on the formdata should be the same with your model properties.

I hope this helps.